# An integer list on python can be used to produce an histogram or a boxplot with ggplot?

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I want to know what kind of data i can used to make histograms on python with ggplot

I have this list :

```
dataUsersNumber=[52854, 149829, 294425, 492003, 10890, 0, 437683, 759]
```

And this is the code that i try to make an histogram :

```
ggplot(aes( y='Number of users'),data=dataUsersNumber)+geom_histogram()
```

I get this :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

So how can i solve my problem ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your code, you can't use 'y=' in aes , arguments can only be :
x
alpha
colour
fill
linetype
size
weight

This is a helpful doc page http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/geom_histogram.html

Comment: Thanks for that doc but it don't solve my problem.  I want to know if i can used my list to build an histogram or i must necessarily transform it into dataframe.

Comment: I remember on R i used to transform in dataFrame or dataTable